# Use function more than once- TimeOut, (document).ready(function(){

Tags: jquery, function, timeout, reload

pretty basic question.
I want to use a function more than just one time. 
This code works but only one time. I have to reload the page if I want to use the function again, which is kind of annoying...

HTML:

```
<div id="phone-header-icon" class="header-icons"></div>
<div id="phonefade">
<div class="close_box">X</div>
<p class="phone-p" id="phone-p-1">Call us!<br/>Monday-friday.</p>
<p class="phone-p" id="phone-p-2">XXX XXX XXXX(phonenumber, the content is not important anyway)</p>
</div>
```

Css:

```
    #phonefade{
background-color:#FFF;
height:100px;
width:33%;
overflow:hidden;
margin-left:15%;
margin-top:2%;
opacity:0.95;
display:none;
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 8px 6px -5px grey;
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).on('click','#phone-header-icon',function(){
  $("#phonefade").css({ display: "block" });
});
$(document).on('click','.close_box',function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $(document).on('click','#phone-header-icon',function(){
   $("#phonefade").show();
 });

 $(document).on('click','.close_box',function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
 });
```

`.remove()` completely removes element from dom.so when u try second time to load the div. 
actually it is not there to show.instead try hiding the div using `hide()`

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aJb43/1/)

i have created a fiddle. it is working fine in it. if still it is causing problem,i think i might be because of some other javascript u might be using

Comment: well this is shorter and actually works but it still is just useable once.

Comment: could you post any other js u might be using

Comment: created a fiddle check it

Answer (score 0):

You are `removing` the particular element from the `DOM` permanently by using [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/). But according to your objective you have to `hide` it.

Try this,

```
$(document).on('click','#phone-header-icon',function(){
  $("#phonefade").show();
});

$(document).on('click','.close_box',function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```